# How to Interpret the Euler Characteristic of Complex Algebraic Varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective (or affine) variety over $\mathbb{C}$ defined by some homogenous ideal $I = (f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. How can we interpret the Euler characteristic of $X$  other than as just an invariant to distinguish non isomorphic objects? What I mean is what could it tell us if anything about either $X$ or the polynomials defining $I$ if $\chi(X) > 0$? How about if $\chi(X) = 0$ or $\chi(X) < 0$? How about in the case of $X$ being a hypersurface cut out by the single (homogeneous) polynomial $f$. What can we deduce about $f$ if $\chi(X) > 0, \chi(X) = 0,$ or $\chi(X) < 0$. I've been trying to relate conditions on the Euler characteristic to anything explicit about the polynomials defining $X$ but haven't had any success so anything that could be said would be interesting and helpful.

Comment: The Euler characteristic is only a topological invariant, so it doesn't seem to tell too much of the scheme structure of $X.$ For a hypersurface, it only tells info about $f$ up to its degree: if the projective hypersurfaces defined by $f=0$ and $g=0$ are both smooth, and $\deg f=\deg g,$ then they are diffeomorphic and hence have the same Euler char. Even the degree of $f$ cannot in general be determined: think of a projective line and a conic in a plane.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question about projective varieties, it is a notable fact that if a complex scheme $X$ is decomposed as a disjoint union of other schemes, then $\chi$ is additive. (Not true for arbitrary decompositions of topological spaces!) So you can think of $\chi$ as a characteristic zero analogue of "counting points over ${\mathbb F}_p$". 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Dori! I think that you will find Paolo Aluffi's paper ["Computing characteristic classes of projective schemes"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204230) useful, if not for the exact formulas, at least for the algorithm.

Among other things it proves the version of the formula in J.C. Ottem's answer for singular hypersurfaces. If $f\in \mathbb C[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ is a non-constant homogeneous polynomial, let $X=\mathcal Z(f)$ and $\Sigma = \mathcal Z_{\mathbb P^n}(\partial_0 f,\dots,\partial_n f)$. If we denote by $g_0,g_1,\dots,g_{n-1}$ the degrees of the gradient morphism 
$$\mathbb P^n\backslash \Sigma\to \mathbb P^n, x=(x_0,\dots,x_n)\to (\partial_0f(x),\dots,\partial_nf(x))$$
then we have 
$$\chi(X)=n+\sum g_i (-1)^{n+1-i}.$$

As far as restricting to graph hypersurfaces, I would say look at the recent papers of Aluffi and Marcolli but you know more than me about these matters so... :)

Added: A toy application of this is in the case of graphs $\Gamma_n$ which have two vertices and $n$ parallel edges, so called banana graphs. the formula above gives
$$\chi(X_{\Gamma_n})=n+(-1)^n$$
so the Euler characteristic determines the graph. The motivic generalization is done in ["Feynman motives of banana graphs"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1690). The motivic viewpoint also shows that one shouldn't expect a nice relation to hold for all graphs, since graph hypersurfaces are generators for the Grothendieck ring (details and actual statement are [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4470)).

Comment: Thanks Gjergji! That's exactly the type of result I was looking for. I hadn't seen that paper or that result in any of their recent papers on graph hypersurfaces. 

Answer (score 10):

This is unlikely unless $X$ is say, a hypersurface. The reason is that the Euler characteristic is invariant of the projective embedding (it is a topological invariant), while the equations defining a variety are certainly not. For example, it is known that *any* projective variety can be defined by determinental quadratic equations in some large projective space.

EDIT: Now, if $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a smooth hypersurface of degree $d$, then we have
$$
\chi(X)=((1-d)^{n+1}-1)d^{-1}+n+1.
$$Hence when $d\ge 3$ or $n$ is odd, one finds that knowing the Euler characteristic would at least give you the degree of the polynomial (the ambiguous cases $d=1,2$ with $n$ even, are easy to distinguish). More generally, when $X$ is a complete intersection, I think there is also some explicit polynomial expressing $\chi(X)$ in terms of the degrees of the generators, but I doubt you can extract any useful information from this.

Comment: Hi John, I think you forgot to divide by $d$ the first part of the formula for the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Also, note that you can reconstruct the degree of $X$ if you know its dimension, with the ambiguity that odd dimensional quadrics have the same cohomology groups (not ring!) as projective space.  I think that, for fixed dimension, this is the only ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, you are right (and it is indeed the only ambiguous case).

Comment: "any projective variety can be defined by determinental quadratic equations in some large projective space." Would you know a place where this is proven?

Comment: This is quite well-known, and goes back to Mumfords  "Varieties defined by quadratic equations", Questions on algebraic varieties, C.I.M.E. Varenna, 1969 , Cremonese (1970) pp. 29–100. To see why, just take any embedding $X\to \mathbb{P}^n$ and take sufficiently many veronese remembeddings of $\mathbb{P}^n$ into some large projective space $\mathbb{P}^N$. In this $\mathbb{P}^N$ the ideal defining $X$ will be defined by linear polynomials (coming from the original embedding) and quadratic binomials defining the veronese variety.  

Comment:  Thanks! Something like that formula is actually extremely useful for me. The hypersurfaces I'm working with are cut out by polynomials that have a very specific form, where each variable appears at most once in every monomial (specifically the Kerchoff polynomial of a graph) so knowing the degree from χ will still be very informative. Is there any generalization of this formula to singular hypersurfaces? Also @MP does your comment refer to using the expression for $\Chi$ that J. C. Ottem gave to deduce the degree or some other technique and if so what?

Comment: We really should be able to edit comments!
